# Test Cases within Python Classes

Tags: python-2.7

I have a class assignment that I am trying to understand surrounding framework.

I have created a StringCalculator class module and then created a test file.

Within the test file that is created to run against my class module, I have numerous "methods". In general, will those "methods" count as a test case or should I be doing more like doctest?

Please forgive me because I am new to programming and am just having a hard time figuring this out surrounding framework and test cases. So please don't put on hold or anything with this post. I am willing to answer any questions you throw my way. Again, I am a newbie. I just need to know if what I am outlining in the code are considered test cases.

The below code is what I have for my test file:

```
import unittest
from StringCalculatorClass2 import StringCalculator

class TestStringCalculatorClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add_empty_string(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("")
        assert 0 == result

    def test_add_one(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("1")
        assert 1 == result

    def test_add_two(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("2")
        assert 2 == result

    def test_add_one_and_two(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("1,2")
        assert 3 == result

    def test_add_five_numbers(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("1,2,17,4,1,1")
        assert 26 == result

    def test_add_with_new_line(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("1,2\n17")
        assert 20 == result

    def test_is_new_delimiter_set(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result1 = string_calculator._is_new_delimiter_set("//;\n1;2;17\n5")
        result2 = string_calculator._is_new_delimiter_set("1;2;17\n5")
        assert True == result1
        assert False == result2

    def test_get_new_delimiter(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator._get_new_delimiter("//;\n1;2;17\n5")
        assert ';' == result

    def test_get_string_without_delimiter(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator._get_string_without_delimiter("//;\n1,2")
        assert "1,2" == result

    def test_call_add_with_new_delimiter(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        result = string_calculator.add("//;\n1;2;17\n5")
        assert 25 == result

    def test_create_error_message_for_negative_numbers(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        negative_numbers = [-1, -2, -3]
        result = string_calculator._create_error_message(negative_numbers)
        assert 'negatives not allowed: -1, -2, -3' == result

    def test_negative_numbers_raises_exception(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        exception_raised = False
        try:
            result = string_calculator.add("-1")
        except Exception:
            exception_raised = True
        assert True == exception_raised

    def test_negative_number_raises_exception_with_message(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        exception_raised = False
        exception_message = ""
        try:
            result = string_calculator.add("-1")
        except Exception as err:
            exception_message = err
            exception_raised = True
        assert True == exception_raised
        assert 'negatives not allowed: -1' == exception_message.args[0]

    def test_multiple_negative_numbers(self):
        string_calculator = StringCalculator()
        exception_raised = False
        exception_message = ""
        try:
            result = string_calculator.add("2,-1,4,-2")
        except Exception as err:
            exception_message = err
            exception_raised = True
        assert True == exception_raised
        assert 'negatives not allowed: -1, -2' == exception_message.args[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: To add this, when I run the test file I get this in PyCharm:   Testing started at 10:50 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 172, in <module>
    module = loadSource(a[0])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 65, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Yes the methods count as test cases. The correct way to do it is to use assert functions of `unittest.TestCase` class instead of having the default python `assert`. So for example for the first test you should have this code:

```
def test_add_empty_string(self):
    string_calculator = StringCalculator()
    result = string_calculator.add("")
    self.assertEqual(result, 0)
```

There are all sorts of asserts in `unittest.TestCase` class, like `assertTrue`, `assertFalse`, ...

You can read more about unit test here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: @JoeDeneca No problem. If it helped please accept the answer.